# NullPointerException with listener and creating objs on button click

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I'm  having some  problems with the code below. It runs, but gives me a this error:

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at controlador.Arbitros_controlador.actionPerformed(Arbitros_controlador.java:125)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectWithKeyChar(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI$Handler.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I  take it from this that the obj, was not  instantiated yet, and but going from the logic of the `if statements`  then it  shouldn't throw this error, and  have been changing it in any way I can think of but it  still throws me the error,  please help.  my code is this:

this is  view class:

```
package vista;

import java.awt.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Arbitros_vista extends JPanel {

public JPanel panel_arbitroNuevo, panel_arbitroInfo, pnombre,
        pnacionalidad, ppartidos, pposicion;
public JTable lista_arbitros;
public JButton partidosAsignados, crear_Arbitro, b3;
public JTextField nombre, nacionalidad, posicion;
public JLabel labelNombre, labelNacionalidad, labelPosicion;
public JComboBox<Integer> opcionesLista;

DateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");

JFormattedTextField entradaFecha = new JFormattedTextField(formatoFecha);
private JLabel amountOfGames;

// constructor creates all components inside the mainWindow tabs
public Arbitros_vista() {

    this.setPanel_nuevo_Arbitro();
    this.crearTablaDeArbitros();
    this.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));

    this.add(this.panel_arbitroNuevo);
    this.add(this.panel_arbitroInfo);

}

public void setPanel_nuevo_Arbitro() {

    panel_arbitroNuevo = new JPanel();

    panel_arbitroNuevo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
            BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(150, 150, 150),      20),
            "Nuevo Arbitro"));

    panel_arbitroNuevo.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    // creacion del label nommbre con su entrada de texto y ubicacion
    // ====================================================================================================

    labelNombre = new JLabel("Nombre:");
    nombre = new JTextField(7);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

    panel_arbitroNuevo.add(labelNombre, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    panel_arbitroNuevo.add(nombre, gbc);

    // creacion del label nacionalidad con su entrada de texto y ubicacion
    // ====================================================================================================

    labelNacionalidad = new JLabel("Nacionalidad:");
    nacionalidad = new JTextField(7);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    panel_arbitroNuevo.add(labelNacionalidad, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    panel_arbitroNuevo.add(nacionalidad, gbc);

    // creacion de label posicion con su entrada de texto y ubicacion
    // ====================================================================================================

    labelPosicion = new JLabel("Posición:");
    posicion = new JTextField(7);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    panel_arbitroNuevo.add(labelPosicion, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    panel_arbitroNuevo.add(posicion, gbc);



    // creacion de DropDown list que contiene opciones para la cantidad de         partidos asignados
    // ====================================================================================================

    amountOfGames = new JLabel("Partidos Asignados");

    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    panel_arbitroNuevo.add(amountOfGames, gbc);

    Integer[] options = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    opcionesLista = new JComboBox<Integer>(options);
    opcionesLista.setSelectedIndex(0);
    opcionesLista.setEditable(false);

    panel_arbitroNuevo.add(opcionesLista, gbc);



    // creacion de boton partidos asignados con su ubicacion
    //         ===========================================================================================      =========

    partidosAsignados = new JButton("Partidos Asignados");

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    panel_arbitroNuevo.add(partidosAsignados, gbc);

    // creacion de boton CREAR ARBITRO con su ubicacion
    // ==============================================================

    crear_Arbitro = new JButton("Crear");

    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    panel_arbitroNuevo.add(crear_Arbitro, gbc);

}// end of setPanel_nuevo_Arbitro method

public void crearTablaDeArbitros() {

    panel_arbitroInfo = new JPanel();
    panel_arbitroInfo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
            BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)),
            "Información Arbitros"));
    panel_arbitroInfo.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    String x = "VS";
    String[] cols = { "Nombre", "Nacionalidad", "Posicion",
            "Partidos Asignados" };
    String[][] rows = { { "esteban rincon", "colombiano",
            "lateral izquierdo", " Ver " } };

    lista_arbitros = new JTable(rows, cols);
    JScrollPane scrol = new JScrollPane(lista_arbitros);
    lista_arbitros.setFillsViewportHeight(false);

    panel_arbitroInfo.add(scrol);

}


}
```

this would be the back end class:

```
package modelo;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 public class Arbitros_modelo {

private String NOMBRE, NACIONALIDAD, POSICION;
private int PARTIDOS_ASIG;
public String[] nom_columns_arbitros = { "Nombre", "Nacionalidad",
        "Posicion", "Partidos Asignados" };
private ConectorBaseDatos conector;

/**
 * Creates Object of type Arbitro that has information about the "Arbitro"
 * 
 * @param nombre
 * @param nacionalidad
 * @param posicion
 */
public Arbitros_modelo(String nombre, String nacionalidad, String posicion,
        int counter) {

    NOMBRE = nombre;
    NACIONALIDAD = nacionalidad;
    POSICION = posicion;
    PARTIDOS_ASIG = counter;
    conector = new ConectorBaseDatos();

    Object[] abr_nombre = { NOMBRE, NACIONALIDAD, POSICION }; // not really
                                                                // necessary
                                                                // ..

}

public String getNOMBRE() {
    return NOMBRE;
}

public String getNACIONALIDAD() {
    return NACIONALIDAD;
}

public String getPOSICION() {
    return POSICION;
}

public int getPARTIDOS_ASIG() {
    return PARTIDOS_ASIG;
}

public void intoARBITROS_TABLE() {

    conector.connect_to_DB("fifa", "root", "");

    conector.InsertIntoDB(
            "INSERT   INTO`arbitros`(NOMBRE,NACIONALIDAD,POSICION,PARTIDOS_ASIGNADOS)"
                    + "VALUES('" + NOMBRE + "', '" +   NACIONALIDAD + "', '"
                    + POSICION + "', '" + PARTIDOS_ASIG + "')",     "fifa",
            "root", "");

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "nuevo arbitro creado !: \n"
            + NOMBRE);

}

}
```

and this would be the controller  where the error is thrown:

```
  package controlador;

 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.util.EventListener;

 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import modelo.Arbitros_modelo;
import modelo.Arbitros_modelo_sub;
import vista.Arbitros_vista;
import vista.Arbitros_vista_sub;

public class Arbitros_controlador implements ActionListener {

private Arbitros_vista VISTA;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Arbitros_modelo MODELO;
private Arbitros_vista_sub vistaSub;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Arbitros_modelo_sub modeloSub;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private String inputOne;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private String inputTwo;
private String nombrE;
private String nacionalidaD;
private String posicioN;
private int counter;

/**
 * Constructor creates a link between all GRAPHICAL INTERFACES AND BACK END|
 * PROCESS
 * 
 * @param vista
 * @param vistasub
 * @param modelo
 * @param modeloSub
 */

public Arbitros_controlador(Arbitros_vista vista,
        Arbitros_vista_sub vistasub, Arbitros_modelo modelo,
        Arbitros_modelo_sub modeloSub) {

    this.VISTA = vista;
    this.vistaSub = vistasub;
    this.MODELO = modelo;
    this.modeloSub = modeloSub;

    this.VISTA.partidosAsignados.addActionListener(this);
    this.VISTA.crear_Arbitro.addActionListener(this);
    this.VISTA.nombre.addActionListener(this);
    this.VISTA.nacionalidad.addActionListener(this);
    this.VISTA.posicion.addActionListener(this);
    this.VISTA.opcionesLista.addActionListener(this);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    counter = (int) this.VISTA.opcionesLista.getSelectedItem();
    if(e.getSource() == this.VISTA.crear_Arbitro){
        nombrE = this.VISTA.nombre.getText();
        nacionalidaD = this.VISTA.nacionalidad.getText();
        posicioN = this.VISTA.posicion.getText();
        this.MODELO = new Arbitros_modelo(nombrE, nacionalidaD, posicioN, counter); // CREATES ARBITRO

        this.MODELO.intoARBITROS_TABLE();
}

    // seeks PARTIDOS ASIGNADOS'S BUTTON
    // ====================================================================================================================================
    if (e.getSource() == VISTA.partidosAsignados) {




        // input validation
        // ====================================================================================================================================

        if (nombrE.equals("") || nombrE.equals(null)
                || nacionalidaD.equals("") || nacionalidaD.equals(null)
                || posicioN.equals("") || posicioN.equals(null)
                || counter == 0) {

            JOptionPane
                    .showMessageDialog(
                            null,
                            "Información del árbitro Incompleta.\n Debe llenar datos primarios"
                                    + " del árbitro antes de continuar con los partidos asignados.");

        } else {






            this.vistaSub = new Arbitros_vista_sub(nombrE);
            this.vistaSub.equTxt.addActionListener(this);
            this.vistaSub.equ2Txt.addActionListener(this);
            this.vistaSub.ok.addActionListener(this);

            this.modeloSub = new Arbitros_modelo_sub(nombrE);

            // end of SUB- VISTA - IF-STATEMENT

        }

        // ====================================================================================================================================================================================

    } else {

        // IF MAIN BUTTON ISN'T CLICKED DO NOTHING
        // ***********************************************************************

    }// END OF first if statement seeks PARTIDOS ASIGNADOS'S BUTTON

    // TODO need to check why its throwing a NullPointerException in next
    // line everytime you pass from and to the JComboBox which gives the
    // option to use X number to create X windows
    // to insert into a ARBITRO_TABLE
    // SEEKS OK BUTTON FOR SUB-VISTA JFRAME
    // ============================================================================================================================================
    if (e.getSource() == this.vistaSub.ok) {

        inputOne = this.vistaSub.equTxt.getText();
        inputTwo = this.vistaSub.equ2Txt.getText();

        // INPUT VALIDATION FOR INNER SUB-VISTA JFRAME COMPONENTS

        if (inputOne.equals("") || inputOne.equals(null)
                || inputOne.equals(" ") || inputTwo.equals("")
                || inputTwo.equals(null) || inputTwo.equals(" ")) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese ambos equipos");

        } else {

            this.modeloSub.intoTable(inputOne, inputTwo);
            this.vistaSub.closeFrame();

        }// END OF INPUT VALIDATION FOR INNER SUB-VISTA JFRAME COMPONENTS

    } else {

    }



}

}
```

and this is where everything is controlled:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

 import modelo.Arbitros_modelo;
import modelo.Arbitros_modelo_sub;
import vista.Arbitros_vista;
import vista.Arbitros_vista_sub;
import controlador.Arbitros_controlador;

public class TESTER_ARBITROS {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Arbitros_vista vista = new Arbitros_vista();
            Arbitros_vista_sub vistaSub = null;
            Arbitros_modelo modelo = null;
            Arbitros_modelo_sub modeloSub = null;

                Arbitros_controlador arbitro = new   Arbitros_controlador(vista, vistaSub, modelo, modeloSub);

            javax.swing.JFrame  frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);                
            frame.add(vista);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
}
```

there is  another class which is the `JFrame` that is created when the button is clicked, but don't think  its  relevant

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: That's a bit general, but correct. I'd rather refer to [how to read a stacktrace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors).

Comment: @AndrewThompson, thanks for the tip I'll  be doing this for a next occasion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main method, you have :

```
Arbitros_vista_sub vistaSub = null;
...
Arbitros_controlador arbitro = new   Arbitros_controlador(vista, vistaSub, modelo, modeloSub);
```

are you sure you enter into the `else` condition of your method `actionPerformed` where you do :

```
this.vistaSub = new Arbitros_vista_sub(nombrE);
```

If not, then you know why you have a NullPointerException

To handle such a NullPointerException, you could add this lines before the one that produce the NPE:

```
if (this.vistaSub == null) {
    this.vistaSub = new Arbitros_vista_sub(nombrE);
}
```

Comment: thanks, how can i handle this error if i want the obj to be created on this button clicked ?  is there  a way  to handle  this error ?

Answer (score 0):

```
at controlador.Arbitros_controlador.actionPerformed(Arbitros_controlador.java:125)
```

Indicates you have a NullPointerException at line 125 in Arbitros_controlador.java; which is the line

```
if (e.getSource() == this.vistaSub.ok) {
```

So I assume `e.getSource()` returns null (which is unlikely), or `this.vistaSub.ok` is null (which is what I expect).